# Copying cells from multiple files in one folder

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a folder that has more than 100 Excel workbooks.

On all of these sheets I need to consolidate two cells of data from each file into one master sheet.

```vb
Sub Macro()

Dim StrFile As String
Dim TargetWb As Workbook
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set TargetWb = Workbooks("Practice.xlsm")

i = 2

StrFile = Dir("\\W.X.com\Y\OPERATIONS\Performance-Reporting\SharedDocuments\Regulatory\Z\X")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(StrFile)

    TargetWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = SourceWb.Sheets("SCR").cell("C24").Value
    TargetWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = SourceWb.Sheets("SCR").cell("B3").Value

    SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

When I run this code, nothing happens.

Comment: Check if the Dir-command returns anything. Is the UNC-Path reachable? Can you see the content with the explorer? Do you have the privileges to read the files?

Comment: And note: `StrFile` will contain only the filename, not the path. You will have to concatenate the path and the filename in the Open-statement

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I do have access to open the files but not to save them. Not too sure about checking if the path is reachable though, how would I go about checking this?

Comment: Is the `Dir`-command returning anything? Try to debug your code and check if it enters the loop at all. For the concatenation: Don't forget to add the backslash between the path and the filename (very common mistake). I would advice that you define a constant with the path

Comment: What kind of files do you try processing? Excel files? CSV files?

Comment: Thanks! It's not entering the loop at all, skipping from the Do While statement, to End Sub. Is this something that is fixable or more likely an access issue? Thanks for the define idea, I'll make certain to implement that once I've got the bulk working.

Comment: They're just xlsx files

Comment: OK. I will post an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, only two cells value is needed to be return, this can be done without opening the workbook, using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. Please, test the next code and send some feedback:

```
Sub Macro()
 Dim StrFile As String, TargetWb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, StrFormula As String
 Const strPath As String = "\\W.X.com\Y\OPERATIONS\Performance-Reporting\SharedDocuments\Regulatory\Z\X\" 'take care of the ending backslash

 Set TargetWb = Workbooks("Practice.xlsm")
 Set ws = TargetWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 i = 2

 StrFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*") 'it returns all files having extensions as xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsa, xlsb
 Dim sheetName As String: sheetName = "SCR"
 Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
     StrFormula = "'" & strPath & "[" & StrFile & "]" & sheetName 
     ws.Range("A" & i).value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(StrFormula & "'!R24C3")
     ws.Range("B" & i).value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(StrFormula & "'!R3C2")
    
    i = i + 1
    StrFile = Dir() 'needed to continue the iteration up to the last file
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Is using `ExecuteExcel4Macro` is better than `ADO` , actually I thought only ADO is able to read excel files without opening it.

Comment: @Waleed Not exactly, from two points of view: You can extract data without opening wb creating a formula using the whole path to the necessary range. But it is not so fast as `ExecuteExcel4Macro`, which is able to return **only a single cell value**. So it cannot be better than `ADO`, generally speaking. You can also use `ADO` to return a cell, probably comparable in terms of speed, but much difficult to configure the connection. The above code is obviously more compact, but limited to the cases of returning separate cells... It can be adjusted to return in an array and then drop it to the rng

Answer (score 0):

If the target sheetnames are static, is there any need to use VBA?
External links are dangerous, but no more so that reading by VBA.

In a new file you can put: ='[File_01.xlsx]sheetname'!$C$24 etc
You need the path in order to use this without opening the target files.
To generate those formulae you can have cells containing the path, the filename, and the sheetname.
(If filenames are sequential numbers, just drag down from the first)
If you name the cells you can do `=Concatenate(path,file,sheet)`
Or if not then something like `=CONCATENATE(,B4,B5,"'!",B6)`
INDIRECT only works with target files open, so at some stage you need to Copy and Paste Value the paths, and put `=` at the front.