# Copying cells from multiple files in 1 folder based on partial file name

Tags: excel, vba

I made a post [Copying cells from multiple files in one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629338/copying-cells-from-multiple-files-in-one-folder).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629338/copying-cells-from-multiple-files-in-1-folder?noredirect=1#comment128295581_72629338) was correct however I need to change it.

The code from this:

```vb
Sub Macro()

 Dim StrFile As String, TargetWb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, StrFormula As String
 Const strPath As String = "\\pco.X.com\Y\OPERATIONS\X\SharedDocuments\Regulatory\Z\X\" 'take care of the ending backslash

 Set TargetWb = Workbooks("X.xlsm")
 Set ws = TargetWb.Sheets("Macro")
 i = 3

 StrFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*") 'it returns all files having extensions as xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsa, xlsb
 Dim sheetName As String: sheetName = "S"
 Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
     StrFormula = "'" & strPath & "[" & StrFile & "]" & sheetName
     ws.Range("B" & i).Value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(StrFormula & "'!R24C3")
     ws.Range("A" & i).Value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(StrFormula & "'!R3C2")
    
    i = i + 1
    StrFile = Dir() 'needed to continue the iteration up to the last file
 Loop
 
End Sub
```

In the folder where I pull the two data points from there are over 1000 workbooks. I only need the data from around 20/30 of these.
I was planning on getting all the data from this folder and then doing a quick play around to get to the stuff I need. The macro to pull from these 1000 docs is causing Excel to crash.

Is it possible to only pull the data from these files if part of the file name matches with a list of codes in the master sheet?

For example, in column B there are 20 codes listed "3333", "44444" , "562872" etc. and the only files I want are "ABCD 3333 BDBD", "AJKP 4444" and "hhhhh 562872 ha".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function InStr() and an array could do the trick:

```
Sub Macro()

    Dim StrFile As String, TargetWb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, StrFormula As String
    Const strPath As String = "\\pco.X.com\Y\OPERATIONS\X\SharedDocuments\Regulatory\Z\X\" 'take care of the ending backslash
    'this is the range where the filename codes are. Change as needed
    Dim arr_files As Variant: arr_files = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("B2:B20")
    Set TargetWb = Workbooks("X.xlsm")
    Set ws = TargetWb.Sheets("Macro")
    i = 3
    
    StrFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*") 'it returns all files having extensions as xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsa, xlsb
    Dim sheetName As String: sheetName = "S"
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        If Not file_to_process(StrFile, arr_files) Then GoTo skip_file
        StrFormula = "'" & strPath & "[" & StrFile & "]" & sheetName
        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(StrFormula & "'!R24C3")
        ws.Range("A" & i).Value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(StrFormula & "'!R3C2")
        i = i + 1
skip_file:
        StrFile = Dir() 'needed to continue the iteration up to the last file
    Loop
 
End Sub
Private Function file_to_process(file_name As String, arr_files As Variant) As Boolean
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In arr_files
        If InStr(1, file_name, Key, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            file_to_process = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Key

End Function
```

I've created a little function to check every filename for every code in the `arr_files` so if one filename has a code in the string, will check as true and get the data.

Comment: Thanks for the crazy quick response Damian! This looks great however I'm getting a compile error with the "Then skip_file" line saying that "Sub or Function not defined" any ideas how to rectify this?

Comment: Sorry @ccornell, forgot to add the "GoTo" the edited code should work now.

Comment: Thank @Damian. sorry for the millions of questions, as you can tell I am pretty new at this level of VBA. Doing the macro this way it's still pulling data from all the files in the folder. Not sure if I explained myself poorly but I only need to pull data from the files that have a name that matches the code in column B so there should only be around 40 or so lines at the end. The file names are "%%CODE%%" and column be is just "CODE", if that explains it any better?

Comment: The `file_to_process` function only checks if the `file_name` passed as parameter has any string in the `arr_files` array. If the `Key` is inside the `file_name` will return true. You could debug the code, click on `For Each Key in arr_files` and press F9, then run the macro. That line will be highlighted in yellow, and you can go line by line pressing F8 so you can see hovering over with your mouse the value for `file_name` and `key` and check if the `InStr` works as intended.

Comment: So it looks like we are skipping from the "If Not file_to_process..." line down to the private function and getting stuck in a loop with the Key. Does that sound as expected?

Comment: Sorry didn't properly read your message. The Key that is being used on that loop is not one of the values contained in the list that should be used as the key, so i don't think that the range is working properly.

Comment: The range is defined in this line: `Dim arr_files As Variant: arr_files = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("B2:B20")` you should point that range to your list with codes.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake of mine, I had the defined range over extended so was excluding blanks beyond the list of codes. Works perfectly now! Thank you